# Swift iOS -How to connect method in UIPopoverBackgroundView Class to a PopoverController in a different class?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller, uiactionsheet

I'm using a PopoverController and I want to get rid of the background shadow. Apple says to subClass the UIPopoverBackgroundView and return `false` for `override class var wantsDefaultContentAppearance: Bool { get }`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverbackgroundview/1619357-wantsdefaultcontentappearance

I subclassed it and set the bool to `false` but the shadow still shows. How do I connect this subclass to the PopoverController that I'm using inside my Actionsheet in my LogoutClass?

UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass:

```
class PopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

override class var wantsDefaultContentAppearance: Bool {
        get {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

LogoutController:

```
class LogoutController:UIViewController{

fileprivate func logOff(){

let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Logging out?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

 let logout = UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .default){
            (action) in
//bla bla bla
}

actionSheet.addAction(logout)

if let popoverController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController{
            popoverController.sourceView = view
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
            window.backgroundColor = .clear
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x:window.bounds.midX, y:window.bounds.midY, width:0, height:0)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []

        }
present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to set `popoverBackgroundViewClass` property of your `UIPopoverPresentationController` instance like so :

**Objective C :**

```
popoverController.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [PopoverBackgroundView class];
```

**Swift**

```
popoverController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = PopoverBackgroundView.self
```

As per Apple docs :

> The default value of this property is nil, which causes the presentation controller to use the default popover appearance. Setting this property to a value other than nil causes the presentation controller to use the specified class to draw the popover’s background content. The class you specify must be a subclass of 
>   UIPopoverBackgroundView
>   .

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried it but the shadow is still there so I'm not sure if it works or not.

Comment: its still not working but your answer is correct. There's something wrong with the background class implementation. Thanks though 